# Removing duplicates (ints) in an array and replacing them with chars

Tags: scala

So i'm trying to make a basic hitori solver, but i am not sure where i should start. I'm still new to Scala.

My first issue is that i'm trying to have an array of some ints (1,2,3,4,2)
and making the program output them like this: (1,2,3,4,B)

notice that the duplicate has become a char B.

Where do i start? Here is what i already did, but didn't do what i excatly need.

```
  val s = lines.split(" ").toSet;

  var jetSet = s
  for(i<-jetSet){

   print(i);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to fold over the numbers, left to right, building the `Set[Int]`, for the uniqueness test, and the list of output, as you go along.

```
val arr = Array(1,2,3,4,2)
arr.foldLeft((Set[Int](),List[String]())){case ((s,l),n) =>
    if (s(n)) (s,"B" :: l)
    else (s + n, n.toString :: l)
}._2.reverse  // res0: List[String] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, B)
```

From here you can use `mkString()` to format the output as desired.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd suggest is to break your program into a number of steps and try to solve those.

As a first step you could transform the list into tuples of the numbers and the number of times they have appeared so far ...

(1,2,3,4,2) becomes  ((1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,1),(2,2)

Next step it's easy to map over this list returning the number if the count is 1 or the letter if it is greater.

That first step is a little bit tricky because as you walk through the list you need to keep track of how many you've seen so far of each letter.

When want to process a sequence and maintain some changing state as you do, you should use a fold. If you're not familiar with fold it has the following signature:

```
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B
```

Note that the type of z (the initial value) has to match the type of the return value from the fold (B).

So one way to do this would be for type B to be a tuple of (outputList, seensofarCounts)

outputList would accumulate in each step by taking the next number and updating the map of how many of each numbers you've seen so far. "seensofarCounts" would be a map of the numbers and the current count.

So what you get out of the foldLeft is a tuple of (((1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,1),(2,2), Map(1 -> 1, 2, 2 ETC ... ))

Now you can map over that first element of the tuple as described above.

Once it's working you could avoid the last step by updating the numbers to letters as you work through the fold.

Usually this technique of breaking things into steps makes it simple to reason about, then when it's working you may see that some steps trivially collapse into each other.

Hope this helps.